# Inserting data into database from html form php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay so I asked a similar question yesterday and was told to learn pdo, I then looked up how to insert data into a database with pdo, and followed the tutorial, and i am having the same problem. The page goes blank and nothing is added to the database.. here is my code

register.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <body>
    <center><h1>Register</h2></center>
    <?php
    if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
    ?>
    <form name='registration' action="register.php" method="post">

     <label for 'user'>Desired Username:</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="User" />
     <br>
      <label for 'pass'>Password:</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="User" />
     <br>

     <label for 'birth'>Birthday (ex: 1992-11-11):</label><br>

     <input type="text" name="Birth" />
     <br>
     <label for 'email'>Email:</label><br>

     <input type="text" name="email" />
     <br>
     <label for 'catch'>Catch Phrase:</label><br>

      <textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="Catch" maxlength="10"></textarea>
     <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 <?php
  } else {
  $db_user = 'a3410999_dom';
 $db_pass = '*****';
 $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=mysql4.000webhost.com;dbname=a3410999_members', $db_user,      $db_pass );

 $form = $_POST;
 $username = $form[ 'user' ];
 $password = $form[ 'pass' ];
 $birth = $form[ 'birth' ];
 $email = $form[ 'email' ];
 $catch = $form[ 'catch' ];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO members ( user, pass, birth, email, catch ) VALUES ( :username,   :password, :birth, :email, :catch )";

 $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
 $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':birth'=>$birth,  ':email'=>$email, ':catch'=>$catch ) );

 } 
  ?>

  </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: `A!=a;` <= just a thought. Plus your password form element is off. This is a debug issue. It's back to the proverbial "drawing board" for you. Classic `C.O.W.` code.

Comment: put your code in the `try ... catch` block to see if anything goes wrong.

Comment: "The page goes blank and nothing is added to the database" - this is typically an indicator that there is a server error. please check the webserver/php error logs for details! They should tell you what is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have mistake here

```
 <label for 'user'>Desired Username:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="User" />
 <br>
  <label for 'pass'>Password:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="User" />
 <br>
```

You set name for "Username" = name AND also the same name for "Password"

Comment: thank you, what a stupid mistake.. so worried about the PHP that i overlooked the html. thank u, it works now :)

Comment: I edited your question by the way. You can't mark your own question as `(solved)`. The way it's done around here is, that once someone gives you an answer that solves your problem, you then click the white checkmark next to the answer, till it turns green. This gives the person who's helped you, reputation points, since he/she went out of his/her way to help in a particular situation. @user3186749

Answer (score 0):

```
   // function for INSERTING DATA IN TABLES
   public function insert($t, $v, $r)
   {
      if (($t != null) && ($r != null) && ($v != null) && (count($v) == count($r)))
      {
         $instruction = 'INSERT INTO `' . DBNAME . '`.`' . $t . '` (';

         for ($i = 0; $i < count($r); $i++)
            $_r[$i] = '`' . $r[$i] . '`';
         $_r = implode(',', $_r);

         $instruction .= $_r . ') VALUES (';

         for ($i = 0; $i < count($r); $i++)
            $r[$i] = ':' . $r[$i];
         $r = implode(',', $r);

         $instruction .= $r . ');';

         $r = explode(',', $r);

         try {
            $statement = $this->PDO->prepare($instruction);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($r); $i++)
               $statement->bindParam($r[$i], $v[$i]);

            if ($statement->execute())
               return true;
            else {
               echo("Error: " . $statement->errorCode());
               return false;
            }
         } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
         }
      } else
         return false;
   }

$t = 'groups';
$v = array( your data );
$r = array( your fields );

if (insert($t, $v, $r))
   echo("ko");
else
   echo("ko");
```

This should work.